# append browse file input does not show preview image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working with javascript. I have append html like

```
<input type="file" class="browse-02 validate[required]" onchange="showMyImage1(this,'thumbnil4')" name="data[question1][question_image4]" id="" />
<img id="thumbnil4" src="images/no_status_image_sp.jpg" class="uploadimg" alt="">
```

This html comes dynamically when click on add more button.

I have written js as shown in below :

```
function showMyImage1(fileInput,id) {
//console.log(fileInput);
var files = fileInput.files;
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var file = files[i];
    var imageType = /image.*/;
    if (!file.type.match(imageType)) {
        continue;
    }

    //alert(id);
    var img = document.getElementById(id);//$("#"+id)[0];
    //alert(img);
    console.log(img);
    img.file = file;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function(aImg) {
        //alert(aImg);
        return function(e) {
            aImg.src = e.target.result;
        };
    })(img);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
}
```

Here, this js does not work for appended data. It gives an error at `img.file = file;` line as `img is null`.

So what javascript should I have to write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I modified your code a little bit, the problem why it is not working because the elements are created dynamically in DOM. So normal event listener will not trigger.

To listen events from dynamically created elements, use Jquery [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) API.

```
$(document).on('change','.browse-btn', function(){
   var thumbnailId = $(this).prev().attr('id');
    showMyImage1(this, thumbnailId)
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        var n = 5;
        var i = 2;
        var j = 10;
        var k = 2;
        
        $('.addmore').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var div = $('#appendData');
            var html  = '';
            html  += '';
            html  += '<div class="formPartd">';
            html  += '<div class="formPartd_left">';
            html  += '<div class="upload-img">';
            html  += '<label>Upload Image'+n+'</label>';
            html  += '<span>';
            html  += '<img id="thumbnil'+j+'" src="" class="uploadimg" alt="">';   
            html  += '<input type="file" class="browse-btn" name="data[question1][question_image'+n+']" />';
             html  += '</span>';
            html  += '<div class="clear10"></div>';
            html  += '</div>';
            html  += '<div class="fildtpart3 pos">';
            html  += '<label>Answer'+n+'</label>';
            html  += '<span><input type="text" class="validate[required]" id="" value=""></span>';
            html  += '<div class="clear10"></div>';
            html  += '</div>';
            html  += '</div>';
            div.append(html);  
            i++;j++;n++;
           // $(document).trigger('updated');

        });
        
        $(document).on('change','.browse-btn', function(){
          var thumbnailId = $(this).prev().attr('id');
          showMyImage1(this, thumbnailId)
        })
    });

function showMyImage1(fileInput,id) {
 //console.log(fileInput);
    var files = fileInput.files;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
        var imageType = /image.*/;
        if (!file.type.match(imageType)) {
            continue;
        }
      
        //alert(id);
        var img = document.getElementById(id);//$("#"+id)[0];
        //alert(img);
        //console.log(img);
        img.file = file;
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (function(aImg) {
         //alert(aImg);
            return function(e) {
                aImg.src = e.target.result;
            };
        })(img);
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="appendData"></div>

<div class="fildtpart2" style="float:right">
               <a href="" type="button " class="csv_button addmore " style="float:right;background:#5a9325">Add More</a>
            </div>
```

Comment: I have tried but it gives same error as `TypeError: img is null`

Comment: give me your email address I will give my site access so you can easily understand.

Comment: @Nisarg sorry but I will keep my identity secret.

Comment: ohk no problem. but have you another way to solve this issue?

Comment: @Nisarg create jsfiddle or codepen. Have you tried clicking run code snippet button in my answer?

Comment: [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/37cms89g/) this is link. You can see my code. But it shows an error that use post method.

Answer (score 0):

The onchange event is called when user select a file, but at this time the file itself won't be accessible. To show it, you need the user to post it, usually via a `<form>`, then saving it. From there, you will be able to show it.

On many modern site, this process looks like being transparent, due to the use of AJAX call :

The onchange event call a jQuery function, that actually send the form (and the image) to a php file. This file save the image, then return the corresponding `<img>` tag, filled with the correct attribute src, that will be append on the page via the Ajax callback.

Comment: Its working for not apended data. But not working for appended data.